# TextArea styles in QML

Tags: qt, qml, stylesheet

I want to change the color of my TextArea object but I don't know how property can do it.

I've tried with

```
TextArea {
    styles: TextAreaStyle {
        borderColor : "green"
    }
}
```

or

```
TextArea {
    TextArea.border.color : "green"
}
```

But both examples doesn't work. I can't found a single property of TextArea for change the border color in the QML reference. Is this possible?, and how can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you read error messages at least? Or just copy the example from the doc http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-styles-textareastyle.html. As for you question - replace "=" with ":". Also there is no property `borderColor` in `TextAreaStyle`.

Comment: @folibis sorry, typo error. Do you see some reference about my problem in that link? (...) I know, there's no borderColor, I'm asking for some property for change the border color, it was only an example. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said there is no `borderColor` in `TextAreaStyle`. But you can do it in "tricky" way:

```
Rectangle {
    color: "green"
    anchors.fill: parent
    anchors.margins: 20

    TextArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 1
        style: TextAreaStyle {
            backgroundColor : "yellow"
        }

    }
}
```